# Unityscript : Instantinate TouchController?

Tags: input, controller, unity-game-engine, touch, unityscript

I am currently creating a joystick and therefore I want to replace the Get Axis method.

Here is my code

```
function UpdateSmoothedMovementDirection () { 
var h = TouchController.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
```

But Unity gives me this error :

> An instance of type 'TouchController' is required to access non static member 'GetAxisRaw'.

How can I call an instance ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add public variable of type `TouchController` to your script. Then add game object with `TouchController` script to your scene. If your script is derived from `MonoBehaviour`, in Hierarchy tab in Unity Editor drag and drop game object with `TouchController` onto your variable.

If your script is not a `MonoBehaviour` script, than you'll have to set this variable manually from some other `MonoBehaviour` script.

Comment: Thank you, I declared a public var of type TouchController and everything worked like charm !